# Using a Singleton to keep track of form data before submitting . . . good idea?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, design-patterns, singleton

Beginner here - I've been reading up on singletons and it seems as many think singletons in most cases, are a characteristic of poor design.

I've got an application in which I am collecting form data like usernames, passwords, emails. However, the data collection is not limited to a single view controller, that is, I've got one view controller that collects one piece data, then i push a new VC that collects another piece of data, etc.

My thought was to create a singleton that could aggregate all the data before submitting it to the web service once all the data has been collected.

My question is, is this an appropriate use of a singleton? What are the alternatives to using a singleton in this situation (ie, how else can i persist that data? to whom would this data collector belong?)

thanks!

Comment: "My question is, is this an appropriate use of a singleton?" No. Singletons are an anti pattern. Always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass it from controller to controller as you move along as a dictionary. Each controller could have a property called `data` and you could pass that along as you go.

Comment: ya this looks like a better solution looks like a better solution . . .

Answer (score 0):

Apple often use Singeltons, but as you have read they are evil.
This is especially true in java, where in test cases you never can remove the Singleton anymore.

The alternative is to create one object at start up and use that.

On ios this woul be located e.g in AppDelegate.m